# escaping double quotes in text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a Jsp page populated with a few textareas and a submit button which does a ajax GET request. user can type in any text. I'm facing problems when user enters a double quoted string or a string containing backslash. I'm currently using encodeURIComponent and JSON.stringify in that order to prepare the get request url parameters. Is that the proper way to do ? The backend code is receiving improper Json object. Here's a sample

User types: `Test "cases" are good` in txtArea0

JS code:

```
var txtData0 = encodeURIComponent($('#txtArea0').val());
var txtData1 = encodeURIComponent($('#txtArea1').val());
var msg = JSON.stringify([{ "id": 0, "txtData" : txtData0},...]);
```

However my server is receiving the msg as `"[{ "id": 0, "txtData" : "Test "cases" are good"},...]"` I'm totally clueless on why this is happening.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: To get properly escaped string, so that i can json parse, something along these lines `[{ "id": 0, "txtData" : "Test \"cases\" are good"},...]"`

Comment: Well you haven't shown how you send the value of "msg" to the server. In any case, I'm pretty sure there's no need to call `encodeURIComponent`. If there is, then you'd need to call it on the entire value of "msg".

Comment: I'm sending the msg as a query string appended to the url.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to encode the entire value of "msg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm currently using encodeURIComponent and JSON.stringify

That's you're problem.
You should only escape when you're actually building a string in that format.

Since you aren't concatenating the values into a URL, you should not be calling `encodeURIComponent`.

If you put the concenate the JSON into a URL, you will need to call `encodeURIComponent` on the resulting JSON string, but no earlier.

In summary

### Escape methods are not a magic sauce that makes your code work.

You need to apply the correct escaping at the correct time.

Comment: I'm actually concatenating the values to a URL. So are you suggesting that I do JSON.stringify before encodeURIComponent ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var txtData0 = $('#txtArea0').val();
var txtData1 = $('#txtArea1').val();
var msg = JSON.stringify([{ "id": 0, "txtData" : txtData0},...]);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/LvGLe/

Comment: The stringified object is sent over url GET request, not performing encodeURIComponent is causing error when the string contains spaces.

Comment: @abhilash you can use `encodeURIComponent` after `converting data` to `string` like `console.log(encodeURIComponent(msg));`

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, and I was receiving an exception when triying to deserialized on the server side, I fixed that problem by double escaping ("if that term exists LoL"), please check the function below:

```
function customEscape(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent( str.replace('\"', '\\\"') );
}
```